# Fix toggle comment functionality for batch files in Sublime Text

Tags: batch-file, sublimetext, sublimetext2

I must be having a bad search day, but I can't find any information about how to customize Sublime Text 2 so that `toggle comment` works correctly for windows batch files (i.e. adding either a `REM` or `::` to the beginning of a line). Any help?

Answer (score 2):

You can create a plugin or a macro to do it. Perhaps a snippet already exists but i have not found it.

I will try to explain the "create macro" alternative.

Create a macro with this code (save it in Packages/User, with name what-you-want.sublime-macro):

```
[
    {"command": "split_selection_into_lines"},
    {"command": "move_to", "args": {"to": "hardbol", "extend": false}},
    {"command": "insert", "args": {"characters": "REM "}}
]
```

Now you can use it. Select the lines to comment and execute the macro.

You can also bind the macro to a key. Add in "Key Bindings - User" this key binding:

```
{ "keys": ["alt+."], "command": "run_macro_file", 
  "args": {"file": "Packages/User/what-you-want.sublime-macro"}, "context":
    [
        { "key": "selector", "operator": "equal", "operand": "source.dosbatch" }
    ]
}
```

The "selector" key in the "context" ensures that this key is only mapped when in batch files ("source.dosbatch").

References:

- [Banish Repetitive Tasks with Sublime Text 2 Macros](http://webdesign.tutsplus.com/tutorials/workflow-tutorials/quick-tip-banish-repetitive-tasks-with-sublime-text-2-macros/)
- [Key binding context to only react on e.g. Python code](http://sublimetext.userecho.com/topic/21146-key-binding-context-to-only-react-on-eg-python-code/)

Comment: Thanks @aanton, that's a great start! However, I'd like to be able to *toggle* the comment (and only in source.dosbatch files). And if I set the key shortcut to Ctrl+/, it overrides the default commenting behavior. So close...

Comment: Hi @Pat. You can set the key shortcut to specific sources (http://sublimetext.userecho.com/topic/21146-key-binding-context-to-only-react-on-eg-python-code/). Anyway, a better option is create a plugin to manage the toggle func.